# ASP.NET Core MVC Check IsAuthenticated for a different AuthenticationScheme

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, umbraco

I have a project with multiple authentication schemes. I can login to a custom scheme successfully, and in my header razor view I call `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and it returns `true` (ultimately I wish to display the username).

I have a different controller without an `[Authorize]` attribute. I want to get the logged-in user from the first/specific/different AuthenticationScheme.

If I use `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` in the second page with a different controller where the scheme is not specified I get `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false`

Is there any way to call `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` (and ultimately get the username) for a non-required scheme?

This is in an Umbraco v10 website which comes with it's own authentication schemes, I'm not sure if that is a spanner in the works or not.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was resolved by correctly setting the Default AuthenticationScheme.

Here's the final config that resolved the issue, particularly note the last few lines. I had tried similar settings but didn't get the exact incantation correct.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCustomMembership(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    //authentication definition
    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0
    services
        .AddAuthentication(MembershipConstants.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(
            MembershipConstants.AuthenticationScheme,
            options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/api/member/log-in/");
                //options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Forbidden");
            }
        );

    services
        .PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(
            MembershipConstants.AuthenticationScheme,
            option =>
            {
                option.Cookie.Name = MembershipConstants.AuthenticationCookieName;
            }
        );

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = MembershipConstants.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = MembershipConstants.AuthenticationScheme;
    });
    services.AddAuthorization();

    return services;
}
```